# SSE nullpointer in ChunkedOutput/OutputBuffer in Jersey Filter on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, server-sent-events

I have a problem ([similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999164/jersey-sse-eventoutput-write-throws-nullpointer-after-first-message-is-sent) ?) which started when I switched jersey (2.19) from a descriptor-less deployment via @ApplicationPath to a  servlet 2.x filter in an existing JAX-RS web application.
As soon as I finished SSE didn't work anymore. As I was using the SSEBroadcaster at the time I built a simpler test method because I didn't get any exceptions with the broadcaster.

Finally the exception popped up:

```
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:150)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:293)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:214)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEventWriter.writeTo(OutboundEventWriter.java:100)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEventWriter.writeTo(OutboundEventWriter.java:63)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:263)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput$1.call(ChunkedOutput.java:219)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput$1.call(ChunkedOutput.java:190)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:242)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput.flushQueue(ChunkedOutput.java:190)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput.write(ChunkedOutput.java:180)
at ch.company.app.controller.MyController$1.run(MyController.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code I used is a variant of the official Jersey documentation found [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#d0e11484):

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("api")
public class MyController {

  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());

  @GET
  @Path("test")
  @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int counter = 0;
                while (!eventOutput.isClosed()) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Eventoutput closed?: " + eventOutput.isClosed());
                    final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                    eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                    eventBuilder.id("c" + counter);
                    eventBuilder.comment("this is a test comment");
                    eventBuilder.data(String.class, "Hello world " + counter + "!");
                    counter++;
                    final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);
                    //Thread.sleep(Integer.toUnsignedLong(5000));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing the event.", e);
            //} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //  Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    eventOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return eventOutput;
  }
}
```

If I only use `eventBuilder.data(...)` and not use `name(), id(), comment()` the exception (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702884/server-sent-event-does-not-work-with-jersey-sse)) would slightly change to this:

```
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:150)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:293)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:214)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEventWriter$1.write(OutboundEventWriter.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:192)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:129)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider.writeTo(StringMessageProvider.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider.writeTo(StringMessageProvider.java:59)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEventWriter.writeTo(OutboundEventWriter.java:127)
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEventWriter.writeTo(OutboundEventWriter.java:63)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:263)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput$1.call(ChunkedOutput.java:219)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput$1.call(ChunkedOutput.java:190)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:242)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput.flushQueue(ChunkedOutput.java:190)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput.write(ChunkedOutput.java:180)
at ch.company.app.controller.MyController$1.run(MyController.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The weird thing is that sometimes, after a restart of Glassfish (4.1) and a new deployment, when calling the method I actually get the desired output from 1 to 90 times (without using the `Thread.sleep()` -> why it's in comments here) only to be followed again by the NullPointerException. And it only does this once as far as I can tell.

Output example before a NullPointerException:

```
: this is a test comment
event: message-to-client
id: c0
data: Hello world 0!
```

My web.xml regarding the jersey servlet 2.x container filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ch.company.app</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>^.+?\.(?:bmp|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|pdf|txt|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|map)$</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<!--
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Since @ApplicationPath generates a Servlet 3.x container I decided to try Servlet 3.x with the following web.xml instead of the Servlet 2.x Filter but it also lead me to the same exception:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ch.company.app</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.disableMoxyJson</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.staticContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>^.+?\.(?:bmp|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|pdf|txt|svg|eot|otf|ttf|woff|map)$</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I even tried to add SseFeature manually (as suggested here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2150) which didn't help either and according to the SSE documentation it's only necessary till jersey version 2.8.

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

So now I spent like two days to getting into this but I still can't figure it out.
Any ideas?

**Update**

I figured out that it only happens when Jersey is configured to run as a filter. I managed to make it work with Servlet 3.x and the web descriptor when omitting the init-params which are not applicable when Jersey is configured as a Servlet, as described here: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ch.company.app.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>ch.company.app.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ch.company.app.ApplicationConfig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the according class

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
  }

  private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(ch.company.app.controller.AppController.class);
    resources.add(ch.company.app.controller.IndexController.class);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I still can't figure out how to access my static ressources (css, js, images) with this approach as the FILTER_STATIC_CONTENT_REGEX is not available in Servlet configuration. (I will investigate this separately.)

So the question is: Why doesn't it work when Jersey is configured as a filter?